# How do I install cURL on cygwin?

Tags: curl, cygwin

I tried to enable curl on cygwin but it says `bash: curl: command not found`

How do I install curl on cygwin?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In the Cygwin package manager, click on curl from within the "net" category. Yes, it's *that* simple.

Comment: As @Casebash said it is the setup.exe and the `Category` name is Net, in that look for package name `curl` and select it.

Comment: It worked for me after couple tries. Make sure you select a server that's in your country.

Comment: I would prefer the method using apt-cyg as stated in other answers.

Comment: The "package manager" is the setup.exe BUT make sure you go through the same installation directories for your Cygwin program files and your Local Package directory so you don't loose previous installed packages. When something can go wrong, it will = Not simple

Comment: but in my case it wasn't available in the package manager doing a local install, but it was with a net install. So you may need to do that.

Answer (score 270):

I just encountered this.

1) Find the cygwin setup.exe file from http://cygwin.com/ and run it. 
2) Click/enter preferences until you reach the "Select Packages" window. (See image) 
3) Click (+) for Net 
4) Click the entry for curl. (Make sure you select the checkbox for the Binary) 
5) Install.  
6) Open a cygwin window and type curl.exe (should be available now).

[image: Cygwin package manager]

Comment: This helped me out considerably. I was having the same issue and was getting absolutely nowhere with the Windows CMD prompt. Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer is definitely more useful per say its easier to follow (more up votes), mentions clearly that setup has to be downloaded from cygwin website. It's a strong candidate of being selected as and answer.

Comment: This might be quicker: Run `setup-x86.exe -q -P curl` in windows cmd window.

Comment: Also you might have to grab libcurl-devel. Wouldn't work for me until I did that.

Comment: I already had the curl package installer, but just after reinstalling the package, the `curl.exe` executable has appeared on `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: 2.5) Can search for curl, that'll cut thru some of the scrolling.  Search box shown in helpful screen above at the top.

Comment: Make sure to click on the circular arrows until the word "Skip" is switched to a current version number for the selected package. Cygwin's gui for this package manager is TERRIBLE

Comment: @ibaralf I know this is a super old post. But thanks for this answer, it seriously helped me. Came form a linux and Mac over to Windows and have been struggling to get Cygwin all set up.

Comment: Thx for help. I had to remove `apt-get remove curl libcurl4 libmetalink3 libopenssl100 zlib0` and then install curl with all dependencies again. Somehow I did not notice I downloaded and installed currupted tar.xz packages.

Answer (score 72):

## Nobody said how to install apt-cyg

in cygwin

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

now you can

```
apt-cyg install curl
```

For more, see the official [github repository](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) of `apt-cyg`.

Comment: This assumes you have `lynx` installed (I don't think it's installed by default).

Comment: Does `apt-cyg` support version targeting, like so `apt-cyg install curl=5.5`??

Comment: @KeithThompson It is possible to use `wget` instead of `lynx`.

Comment: awesome, thanks
For me: lynx -source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg and also "apt-cyg update"

Answer (score 33):

`apt-cyg` is a great installer similar to apt-get to easily install any packages for Cygwin.

```
$ apt-cyg install curl
```

**Note:** `apt-cyg` should be first installed. You can do this from Windows command line:

```
cd c:\cygwin
cygwinsetup.exe -q -P wget,tar,qawk, bzip2,vim,lynx
```

Close Windows cmd, and open Cygwin Bash.

```
$ lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg install apt-cyg /bin
$ chmod +x /bin/apt-cyg
```

Comment: Sorry. Why not just install curl using setup.exe directly: `setup-x86.exe -q -P curl`. But thanks for the post. Did not know the cygwin setup's command line use before.

Comment: Once installed, with ``apt-cyg`` you have a bunch of comfortable possibilities to manage your packages, like searching or updating packages, list install packages and their dependencies, and more, just like using apt-get or yum on a regular linux shell.

Comment: I edited the question for updated installation method

Comment: How to install the `lynx `.

Comment: Not working for me. It did some processing but in the end cmd prompt hangs.

Answer (score 19):

In order to use the command-line version of curl, you need the curl executable.
So, run the Cygwins Setup.exe, and select curl (under Net->curl). That one uses libcurl3, which is located in Libs->libcurl3. But libcurl3 will be pulled in as a dependency if it's not already installed.
So, just select Net->curl and you're good to go.

Answer (score 10):

In order to install any package,we must first find the setup.exe file.I could not locate this file.so i downloaded this file (or you can do a wget).I am on windows64 bit.So ,if you go to https://cygwin.com/install.html  ,you can download  setup-x86_64.exe file from the install and updates section,move this setup-x86_64.exe to your c:/cygwin64,and then run it from there ( setup-x86_64.exe -q -P curl)

Comment: Installer was in my Downloads folder

Answer (score 4):

I searched for curl on the cygwin packages part of their home page.

I found this link `http://cygwin.com/packages/curl/`.
But that wasn't helpful because I couldn't download anything

So I searched for the `curl-7.20.1-1 cygwin` on Google.
I found this helpful site `mirrors.xmission.com/cygwin/release/curl/`

That site had a link to download `curl-7.20.1-1.tar.bz2`. I unzipped it using 7zip. It unzips it into `./user/bin/` or something so I had to find `curl.exe` in the local `/usr/bin` folder and put it into my `/bin` folder of `c:\cygwin`

Finally I could use cURL!

This drove me crazy. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Next time use cygwin's setup.exe it will just let you install packages from there. You can also get a program called cyg-apt which works like Debian/Ubuntu's apt-get. http://code.google.com/p/cyg-apt/

Comment: I tried to run setup.exe, but I couldn't find curl in the list. I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this.

If you're not seeing curl in the list (see ibaralf's screenshot), then you may have out-of-date cygwin sources. In one of the screens in cygwin's setup.exe wizard, you have the option to "Install from Internet" or "Install from Local Directory". If you have the  "Install from Local Directory" option enabled, then you may not see curl in the list. Switch to "Install from Internet" and select a mirror and then you should see curl.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
apt-cyg install curl
```

Comment: `apt-cyg: command not found`

Is this only available on newer versions of Cygwin, or is it just a package that needs installed?  My version is 1.7.16.

Comment: apt-cyg is a command-line installer for Cygwin which cooperates with Cygwin Setup and uses the same repository. The syntax is similar to apt-get https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/

Comment: That's because you need to install ``apt-cyg`` first. See https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Cygwin comes with many packages ([among them curl, as you found](http://cygwin.com/packages/curl/)) to install one of them you run the `setup.exe` program.

Comment: I have cygwin installed on windows 7.  I cant find setup.exe.  doing: "apt-cyg install curl" gives command not found.  Doing "$ cd c:\cygwin" gives no such file or dir.  Start->allprogs->cygwin doesnt have start.exe or similar, only terminal.  So I can launch a terminal, but not start.exe.  Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot find a setup.exe either.HELP

Comment: Setup should have initialized before confirming the installation. If you missed that step may have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is having problem with finding CURL in the list in setup.exe (Cygwin package manager) then trying downloading 64bit version of this setup. Worked for me.

Comment: Also you can try different server, as some of them doesn't have some packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see a certain package, you can access to a full list of ports (also unnoficials, the packages you see on the web) launching the setup.exe with `-k` argument with value `http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg` (example: **`C:\cygwin\setup\setup-x86.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg`**).

Doing so, you can choose a lot of extra packages, also extra versions of cURL (compat one).
I do that to get Apache, cUrl, php5, php5-curl and some others :)

I don't know if apt-cyg can get those extra packages.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the folder "curl-7.43.0" from zip file that I downloaded from curl website [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/) into cygwin64 folder on drive C:. And then I have used it with prefix curl in cygwin command terminal.

[My actual download location from softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/cURL.shtml#download), I have used Softpedia Mirror (US)

Comment: If you install it directly, bypassing the Cygwin `setup*.exe` utility, you won't get updates.

Comment: When you are on a computer with no administrator privileges my method can help, 

Also I am not so sure that you can't update it manually with console,

I don't have cygwin right now on my computer, and I don't use it any more, so you can try methods that are described in this [thread](http://superuser.com/questions/214831/how-to-update-cygwin-from-cygwins-command-line).

and also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Installing and Updating Cygwin for 64-bit versions of Windows
>
> Run setup-x86_64.exe any time you want to update or install a Cygwin
>   package for 64-bit windows. The signature for setup-x86_64.exe can be
>   used to verify the validity of this binary using this public key.

https://cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows system where you want to install Cygwin with cURL download and run the Cygwin installer

64-bit: cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe
32-bit: cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe
(if already installed, go to the setup file existed path)

D:\cygwin\setup (where the Cygwin is existed)

Click on the setup (setup-x86_64)

Follow the prompts in the Cygwin Setup wizard.

You can leave most settings at their default values. Pay specific attention to the following:

In the Select Your Internet Connectioin screen, select "Install from Internet".

In the Choose a download site screen, choose a site from the list, or add your own sites to the list, I have Chosen a: “mirrors.xmission.com”

The Select Packages screen displays a list of all the available packages and lets you select those you want to install. By default, only the packages in the "Base" category are marked for installation. The "Base" category does not include tools like cURL. You should select those explicitly.

By default, the packages are grouped by category. Click the View button to toggle to the Full view

Select all the curl packages by clicking the "Skip" button for each package once. Note how the "Skip" label changes to show the version number of the selected package.

[the Select Packages screen should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpnMd.png)

Click Next through the rest of the wizard. The selected packages are downloaded and installed.

It worked for me and it resolved the issue : bash curl command not found cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libcurl-devel` worked for me.
Run cygwin setup. After you reach the **Select package** window search for curl, [as shown in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/engz8.png). Select `libcurl-devel` and install the package.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score -1):

Even below will install curl

> cd c:\cygwin
>   setup.exe -q -P curl