# How do I install cygwin components from the command line?

Tags: command-line, cygwin

Is there a tool in the Cygwin package similar to `apt-get` on Debian or `yum` on redhat that allows me to install components from the command line?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

There is no tool specifically in the 'setup.exe' installer that offers the
functionality of apt-get. There is, however, a command-line package installer
for Cygwin that can be downloaded separately, but it is not entirely stable and
relies on workarounds.

apt-cyg: http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

Check out the issues tab for the project to see the known problems.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted to know. I wonder why they aren't mature?

Comment: Good question. I'm not entirely sure of the answer, actually.

Comment: @vy32: because you didn't help to make them mature? :) They can't write themselves. Someone have to work on them. And since their usability is quite limited (to overwrite files currently in use on Windows you have to close Cygwin first, so it's not possible to execute any package manager in closed Cygwin :), there isn't many  people interested.

Comment: From another answer: `setup-x86.exe -q -P packagename1,packagename2`. Not as fancy as `apt-get` or even `apt-cyg` but it does the trick in most cases. And you can also run this from `cmd.exe` (after closing Cygwin).

Comment: @Steve , the answer by Dawid says it moved to "sage".  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23143997/80772

Comment: Since the original project is dead, I suggest looking at this (as of the time of this comment) active fork: https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Wow, wasn't aware of this and I've been using the transcode version for years - thanks!

Answer (score 161):

Cygwin's setup accepts [command-line arguments](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli) to install packages from the command-line.

e.g. `setup-x86.exe -q -P packagename1,packagename2` to install packages without any GUI interaction ('unattended setup mode').

(Note that you need to use `setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe` as appropriate.)

See https://cygwin.com/packages/ for the package list.

Comment: Nice! setup.exe is now called setup-x86.exe - or a variant depending on cpu bits. Also see here for the package list http://cygwin.com/packages/

Comment: Also, to specify multiple packages, separate them with commas. e.g. in DOS, type `setup-x86_64 --packages="openssh,python"`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of setting up specific versions.

Comment: @jturney, Is this stable?

Comment: @Pacerier, It's unclear what you are asking. This should be a feature of setup that it's safe to rely on.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=cygwin-setup.git;a=blob;f=package_meta.cc;h=1c6183c638d059a3236c76c18d5dc56d4be75e3c;hb=HEAD#l351 shows that -P accepts packageName=version pairs. And the feature announcement is at https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2021-April/010021.html

Comment: Just to be clear, `-P packagename=version` is a new feature. Just `-P packagename` has been accepted for a long time (and still is) ...

Answer (score 143):

For a more convenient installer, you may want to use
`apt-cyg` as your package manager. Its syntax similar to
`apt-get`, which is a plus. For this, follow the above
steps and then use Cygwin Bash for the following steps

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
chmod +x apt-cyg
mv apt-cyg /usr/local/bin
```

Now that `apt-cyg` is installed. Here are few examples of
installing some packages

```
apt-cyg install nano
apt-cyg install git
apt-cyg install ca-certificates
```

Comment: Obviously use setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget,tar,qawk,bzip2,subversion,vim for 64 bit windows.

Comment: Needed to add --no-check-certificate to the wget command. Otherwise, superb.

Comment: And now it's a 404 (after a few redirects)

Comment: Just tried `wget` and it downloads `apt-cyg` without problems. At what point does the 404 appear?

Comment: wget is not installed by default with cygwin, meaning this needs to be bootstrapped with a manual and non-programmatic installation.

Comment: `apt-cyg` now allows fallback to `lynx` out-of-the-box. You could then use `apt-cyg` to install `wget` if you need that or simply don't want to see the warnings about the fallback.

Comment: `wget, lynx, setup-x86.exe, setup-x86_64.exe` **are not recognized as internal or external commands**. Now what? What is the first thing i should do after installing `cygwin` ? I'm super confused about all this steps. Any advice?

Comment: Re: akauppi's comment. Don't add `--no-check-certificate` unless you really know what you're doing. I would almost never recommend disabling certificate validation. It's a security risk.

Comment: apt-cyg does not seem to install dependencies. For example, if I install rsync it won't install libcyxxhash and it results in an error: `rsync.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygxxhash-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 59):

There exist some scripts, which can be used as simple package managers for Cygwin. But it’s important to know, that they always will be quite **limited**, because of...ehm...Windows.

Installing or removing packages is fine, each package manager for Cygwin can do that. But updating is a pain since Windows doesn’t allow you to overwrite an executable, which is currently running. So you can’t update e.g. Cygwin DLL or any package which contains the currently running executable from the Cygwin itself. There is also this note on the [Cygwin Installation](https://cygwin.com/install.html) page:

> "The basic reason for not having a more full-featured package manager is that
> such a program would need full access to all of Cygwin’s POSIX functionality.
> That is, however, difficult to provide in a Cygwin-free environment, such as
> exists on first installation. Additionally, Windows does not easily allow
> overwriting of in-use executables so installing a new version of the Cygwin
> DLL while a package manager is using the DLL is problematic."

Cygwin’s setup uses Windows registry to overwrite executables which are in use
and this method **requires a reboot of Windows**. Therefore, it’s better to **close
all Cygwin processes before updating packages**, so you don’t have to reboot
your computer to actually apply the changes. Installation of a new package
should be completely without any hassles. I don’t think any of package managers
except of Cygwin’s `setup.exe` implements any method to overwrite files in use,
so it would simply fail if it cannot overwrite them.

---

## Some package managers for Cygwin:

### [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

**Update**: the repository was disabled recently due to copyright issues ([DMCA takedown](http://web.archive.org/web/20160128185112/https://github.com/github/dmca/blob/master/2016-01-26-apt-cyg.md)). It [looks like](https://web.archive.org/web/20160128194827/https://github.com/svnpenn/sage/issues/2) the owner of the repository issued the DMCA takedown on *his own* repository and created a new project called *Sage* (see bellow).

The best one for me. Simply because it’s one of the most recent. It doesn’t use Cygwin’s `setup.exe`, it rather re-implements, what `setup.exe` does. It works correctly for both platforms - *x86* as well as *x86_64*. There are a lot of forks with more or less additional features. For example, the **[kou1okada fork](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) is one of the improved versions**, which is really great.

*apt-cyg* is just a shell script, there is no installation. Just download it (or clone the repository), make it executable and copy it somewhere to the PATH:

```sh
chmod +x apt-cyg # set executable bit
mv apt-cyg /usr/local/bin # move somewhere to PATH
# ...and use it:
apt-cyg install vim
```

There is also [bunch of forks](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg#forks-on-the-github) with different features.

---

### [sage](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611151310/https://github.com/svnpenn/sage)

Another package manager implemented as a shell script. I didn't try it but it actually looks good.

It can search for packages in a repository, list packages in a category, check dependencies, list package files, and more. It has features which other package managers don't have.

---

### [cyg-apt](https://github.com/nylen/cyg-apt)

Fork of abandoned original [<del>cyg-apt</del>](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cyg-apt/) with improvements and bugfixes. It has quite a lot of features and it's implemented in Python. Installation is made using `make`.

---

### [Chocolatey’s cyg-get](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get)

If you used Chocolatey to install Cygwin, you can install the package *cyg-get*, which is actually a simple wrapper around Cygwin’s `setup.exe` written in PowerShell.

---

### Cygwin’s setup.exe

It also has a [command line mode](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli). Moreover, it allows you to **upgrade all installed packages at once** (as `apt-get upgrade` does on Debian based Linux).

Example use:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q --packages=bash,vim
```

You can create an alias for easier use, for example:

`alias cyg-get="/cygdrive/d/path/to/cygwin/setup-x86_64.exe -q -P"`

Then you can, for example, install *Vim* package with:

`cyg-get vim`

Comment: `sage` is a fork of `apt-cyg` by its most active contributors over the past year or two (Steven Penny). It appears that earlier this year he had some disagreement with the original `apt-cyg` author (Stephen Jungels) and issued the DMCA takedown when he forked the project. Since Jungels (aka Transcode) is verifiably the original author of the project, GitHub restored the original project soon after. Currently, both projects are available – though the original project hasn't had any new code updates since the split. It’s a messy situation, really.

Comment: setup-x86_64.exe -q --packages=bash,vim. This approach has helped me in the past. Just run it from command line and it works smoothly.

Comment: The sage project is no longer hosted on GitHub, at least not at that URL. I've submitted an edit which replaces it with an archive URL, but I don't know whether the project still exists at a different location or not.

Answer (score 13):

First, download installer at: https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe (Windows 64bit), then:

```
# move installer to cygwin folder
mv C:/Users/<you>/Downloads/setup-x86_64.exe C:/cygwin64/

# add alias to bash_aliases
echo "alias cygwin='C:/cygwin64/setup-x86_64.exe -q -P'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases

# add bash_aliases to bashrc if missing
echo "source ~/.bash_aliases" >> ~/.profile
```

e.g.

```
# install vim
cygwin vim

# see other options
cygwin --help
```

Comment: I'm using a method very similar to this and it's working really well for me, providing you know the names of the packages you want to install beforehand that is ;-)

Comment: very simple solution.  just added the alias to .bashrc

Comment: This is so simple and so great. Chapeau!

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a solution for this similar to `apt-get --print-uris`, but unfortunately apt-cyg doesn't do this. The following is a solution that allowed me to download only the packages I needed, with their dependencies, and copy them to the target for installation. Here is a bash script that parses the output of `apt-cyg` into a list of URIs:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

package=$1
depends=$( \
    apt-cyg depends $package \
    | perl -ne 'while ($x = /> ([^>\s]+)/g) { print "$1\n"; }' \
    | sort \
    | uniq)
depends=$(echo -e "$depends\n$package")
for curpkg in $depends; do
    if ! grep -q "^$curpkg " /etc/setup/installed.db; then
    apt-cyg show $curpkg \
        | perl -ne '
            if ($x = /install: ([^\s]+)/) { 
                print "$1\n"; 
            }
            if (/\[prev\]/) { 
                exit; 
            }'
    fi
done
```

The above will print out the paths of the packages that need downloading, relative to the cygwin mirror root, omitting any packages that are already installed. To download them, I wrote the output to a file `cygwin-packages-list` and then used wget:

```
mirror=http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com/
uris=$(for line in $(cat cygwin-packages-list); do echo "$mirror$line"; done)
wget -x $uris
```

The installer can then be used to install from a local cache directory. Note that for this to work I needed to copy `setup.ini` from a previous cygwin package cache to the directory with the downloaded files (otherwise the installer doesn't know what's what).

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but still relevant. Here is what worked for me today (6/26/16).

From the bash shell:

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Comment: `wget` or `curl` is probably a better tool for this. (And personally, I'd install it in some other directory in my `$PATH` rather than in `/bin`.)

Answer (score 4):

Dawid Ferenczy's answer is pretty complete but after I tried almost all of his options I've found that the [Chocolatey’s cyg-get](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get) was the best (at least the only one that I could get to work).

I was wanting to install `wget`, the steps was this:

```
choco install cyg-get
```

Then:

```
cyg-get wget
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually before installing a package one has to know its exact name:

```
# define a string to search
export to_srch=perl

# get html output of search and pick only the cygwin package names
wget -qO- "https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=$to_srch&arch=x86_64" | \
perl -l -ne 'm!(.*?)<\/a>\s+\-(.*?)\:(.*?)<\/li>!;print $2'

# and install 
# install multiple packages at once, note the
setup-x86_64.exe -q -s http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -P "<<chosen_package_name>>"
```