# apt-get for Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, apt-get

Is there any `apt-get`-like program for use with Cygwin?

I've already tried `cyg-apt`, but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
cyg-apt: downloading: http://cygwin.mirrors.pair.com/setup-2.bz2
cyg-apt: downloading: http://cygwin.mirrors.pair.com/setup-2.ini
cyg-apt: bad URL http://cygwin.mirrors.pair.com/setup-2.ini, exiting.
```

Comment: The file is available in the source repository.

Comment: Is it possible to download from a different repo than cygwin? Actually, I need some linux-headers for a computer offline with linux but I need to download them on windows with an apt-get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install cygwin components from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line)

Comment: **cyg-apt** has the last update 5 year ago. Current repository structure is different. Therefore it won't work.

Comment: don't confuse `cyg-apt` with `apt-cyg`. The latter is much better (just remember the one that sounds most similar to `apt-get` is the good one).

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Best I have ever used:

[apt-cyg package manager](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

Comment: apt-cyg orks really well. Just installed rsync, openssh, mc and others.

Comment: It can only install and remove packages, can't it? It's not possible to upgrade particular package or all packages to the newest version with apt-cyg. So it's nice, but useless since I have to use Cygwin's setup too. I would be pleased if I'm wrong.

Comment: `apt-cyg update` will update setup.ini etc, if anyone has issues without of date setup.ini

Comment: Are there any mirrors?

Comment: @CodeMonkey The repo is back up, along with it's competitor: [Sage](https://github.com/svnpenn/sage)

Answer (score 106):

You can do this using Cygwin’s setup.exe from Windows command line. Example:

```
cd C:\cygwin64
setup-x86_64 -q -P wget,tar,gawk,bzip2,subversion,vim
```

For a more convenient installer, you may want to use the
[apt-cyg package manager](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). Its syntax is
similar to apt-get, which is a plus. For this, follow the above steps and then
use Cygwin Bash for the following steps:

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Now that `apt-cyg` is installed. Here are a few examples of installing some
packages:

```
apt-cyg install nano
apt-cyg install git
apt-cyg install ca-certificates
```

Comment: after doing above step apt-cyg for 64 bits gives exception /usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 1: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 3: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 19: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 21: $'\r': command not found
/usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
'usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 27: `  || test "-$GAWK-" = "--"

Comment: @sagunms it worked charm! this was annoying issue until i found the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Shahjahan Khan: It seems, that you broke line endings with some Windows text editor. Use Linux line endings (\n or LF or 0x0A), not Windows (\r\n or 0x0D 0x0A or CR LF).

Comment: hey.. how would i install gcc using that tool suppose i forgot to install the Devel packages while installing cygwin

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/apt-cyg: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token \`newline'`

Comment: Works for me! a

Comment: `cd C:\cygwin64` was not necessary for me since I had just downloaded the cygwin install and the setup.exe file was in my Downloads/ directory so I cd'd into my Downloads/ directory then ran the second command you gave. Just figured I'd share for documentation and to help others

Comment: @ShahjahanKhan @JackHasaKeyboard and maybe others : `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/setup-x86_64.exe dos2unix` (it might take you to the GUI setup installer. Just follow the steps.) Then `dos2unix apt-cyg` and follow the rest of the instructions. The problem is that you have Windows- or OS-like line endings, whereas Cygwin expects Linux-like endings. @DawidFerenczy described this, but I want to show a concrete example of how to implement his solution.

Answer (score 28):

**Update:** you can read the [more complex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143997), which contains more methods and information.

There exists a couple of scripts, which can be used as simple package managers. But as far as I know, none of them allows you to upgrade packages, because it’s not an easy task on Windows since there is not possible to overwrite files in use. So you have to close all Cygwin instances first and then you can use Cygwin’s native setup.exe (which itself does the upgrade via “replace after reboot” method, when files are in use).

---

### [apt-cyg](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

The best one for me. Simply because it’s one of the most recent. It works correctly for both platforms - x86 and x86_64. There exists a lot of forks with some additional features. For example the [kou1okada fork](http://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) is one of improved versions.

---

### Cygwin’s setup.exe

It has also [command line mode](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli). Moreover it allows you to upgrade all installed packages at once.

```
setup.exe-x86_64.exe -q --packages=bash,vim
```

Example use:

`setup.exe-x86_64.exe -q --packages="bash,vim"`

You can create an alias for easier use, for example:

`alias cyg-get="/cygdrive/d/path/to/cygwin/setup-x86_64.exe -q -P"`

Then you can for example install the *Vim* package with:

`cyg-get vim`

Answer (score 19):

you can always make a bash alias to setup*.exe files in $home/.bashrc

cygwin 32bit

```sh
alias cyg-get="/cygdrive/c/cygwin/setup-x86.exe -q -P"
```

cygwin 64bit

```sh
alias cyg-get="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/setup-x86_64.exe -q -P"
```

now you can install packages with

```sh
cyg-get <package>
```

Answer (score 7):

This got it working for me:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > \
apt-cyg && install apt-cyg /bin
```

Comment: ```wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg  && install apt-cyg /bin``` is another option if curl is missing

Comment: Also remember ```rm apt-cyg``` afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

No. The only officially supported tool for downloading and updating Cygwin packages is the [setup.exe file you used for the initial install](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html), although that can be invoked with command line arguments to help the process.

From that same page:

> The basic reason for not having a more full-featured package manager is that such a program would need full access to all of Cygwin's POSIX functionality. That is, however, difficult to provide in a Cygwin-free environment, such as exists on first installation. Additionally, Windows does not easily allow overwriting of in-use executables so installing a new version of the Cygwin DLL while a package manager is using the DLL is problematic.

Comment: Those were some good details on why this is not generally possible. Should be included in the cyg-get or apt-cyg docs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get) to install `cyg-get` and then install your packages with it.

For example:

```
choco install cyg-get
```

Then:

```
cyg-get install my-package
```

Comment: Unfortunately this downloads Cygwin setup `setup-x86_64.exe` and installs Cygwin again, not just `apt-cyg`. I had to cancel the installation.

Comment: I think this didn't happen to me :/

Comment: Works well here. Easy to remember and searchable on [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=cyg%2Dget).