# Can't use cyg-apt on cygwin 1.7

Tags: cygwin

I've got an issue with the cyg-apt command (on cygwin 1.7 running on a Windows 7 64bits virtual machine)

I've followed these step in order to install cyg-apt correctly :

```
Install cygwin  
Install wget and python  
wget http://www.lilypond.org/~janneke/software/cyg-apt 1.1  
Edit the cygapt file: Change the default server to other than the one in it. (I find   ftp://ftp.cise.ufl.edu/pub/mirrors/cygwin/ to be good)  
chmod a+rx cyg-apt  
mv cyg-apt /bin  
cyg-apt setup  
cyg-apt update
```

And no matter what I try with cyg-apt (cyg-apt install package-name, cyg-apt man, even cyg-apt ...), this error appear everytime :

```
to rely on a native Windows version of Bonjour's mDNSResponder service.  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/bin/cyg-apt", line 658, in (module) get_setup_ini()  
File "/usr/bin/cyg-apt", line 184, in get_setup_ini raise 'URG'  
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived form BaseException, not str
```

I've made some researchs and it could be link to an incompatibility with the 1.7 version of cygwin but nothing more helpfull.

Comment: It looks like `apt-cyg` doesn't handle `message:` tags in `setup.ini` properly.

Comment: @Yaakov apt-cyg and cyg-apt are entirely different.  Does cyg-apt also not handle `message:` tags in `setup.ini` properly?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `cyg-apt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly not exactly what you’re looking for, but perhaps abandon cyg-apt in
favor of [apt-cyg](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). cyg-apt hasn’t been updated since 2009. Personally,
whenever I try cyg-apt update I get an error like this:

```
cyg-apt: bad URL http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/setup-2.ini, exiting.
```

the apparent solution to which is to instead use apt-cyg.

[apt-get for cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9751845)

Comment: I saw apt-cyg during my research. I'm gonna test it.

Comment: apt-cyg works pertfectly (https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/) ans apt-cyg is clearly deprecated.
Thank you Adam R. Grey

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using Cygwin's setup.exe from Windows command line. Example:

```
cd c:\cygwin
setup.exe -q -P wget,tar,qawk,bzip2,subversion,vim
```

For a more convenient installer, you may want to use *apt-cyg* as your package
manager. Its syntax similar to *apt-get*, which is a plus. For this, follow the
above steps and then use Cygwin Bash for the following steps:

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Now that *apt-cyg* is installed. Here are few examples of installing some
packages:

```
apt-cyg install nano
apt-cyg install git
apt-cyg install ca-certificates
```

Comment: apt-cyg is also broken in 32 bit installers. To fix that just replace x86_64 with x86 in /usr/local/bin/apt-cyg. In fact, I'd recommend only changing the variable "mirror=ftp://mirror.mcs.anl.gov/pub/cygwin/x86" in Line 68.