# cygwin apt-get: command not found

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, apt-get, x11

I installed cygwin om windows 7.

I also need to install some packages, when I try to use the command-

```
 apt-get install gstreamer-dbus-media-service gstreamer-tools gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-buzztard gstreamer0.10-buzztard-doc gstreamer0.10-crystalhd gstreamer0.10-doc gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg-dbg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs gstreamer0.10-gnonlin gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-dbg gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-doc gstreamer0.10-hplugins gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-packagekit gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-doc gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-dbg gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-doc gstreamer0.10-plugins-cutter gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-doc gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-doc gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-qapt gstreamer0.10-sdl gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-vaapi gstreamer0.10-vaapi-doc gstreamer0.10-x
```

I get this error:

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

I saw similar problems and solutions, for example- this link

https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/

but its not working

**edit:**
I followed the command and this is the error I get:

```
$ apt-cyg install nano
/usr/bin/apt-cyg: line 19: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/apt-cyg: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
'usr/bin/apt-cyg: line 27: `  || test "-$GAWK-" = "--" || test "-$XZ-" = "--"
```

I will be happy for some help.

thank you.

Comment: Since this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751845/apt-get-for-cygwin) points at the same link you have linked, and you claim it does not work, we could best help you if you explained why it did not work.

Comment: I edited my question. thank you.
the link I provide is from the answer with the 35 "likes"

Comment: @user3378689 The "likes" are known as *upvotes*, and their opposite, *downvotes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you show seems to be related to Windows-style newlines messing up `cygwin`.

If you have `dos2unix` available, try running `dos2unix apt-cyg` on wherever `apt-cyg` is.

If you do not have `dos2unix`, take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/612435/cygwin-dos2unix-command-not-found) for where to install it from.

Also, take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/cygwin-r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile).

Clarification on Usage:

1. Run `dos2unix` on the file `apt-cyg` **only**. That is, run the command `dos2unix apt-cyg`. The purpose is to "fix" the file `apt-cyg`, so that it will work properly, where it is failing now.
2. Run `apt-cyg` the same way you did in your question. **Do not** prepend the command with `dos2unix`.

Comment: o.k.. I tried dos2unix and when I tried to " dos2unix apt-cyg install nano" 

I got this:dos2unix: converting file apt-cyg to Unix format ...
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x00 found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file install
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x00 found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file nano


I dont think that this is o.k...

Comment: @user3378689, Please see the edited answer for clarification, and apologies for the initial ambiguity.