# how to install emacs on cygwin

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I have already installed cygwin and I have been using it for sometime.I installed emacs on a remote machine(amazon ec2).But I would like to access emacs on my local machine in cygwin(when I am not connected to my ec2 instance).I do not want to re-run the setup.exe file and include emacs as a packege.Which other way can I do it?...If possible install it directly from the cygwin terminal.
  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install cygwin components from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line)

Comment: If you have installed `curl` or `wget`, grab a Windows build from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip . Then extract it into `/usr/local/lib/`, symlink the executables in the `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure `$HOME` set in your environment to your user directory in Cygwin. There is also this eLisp file you'd want to use: https://github.com/mizhi/dot-emacs/blob/master/elisp/setup-cygwin.el (also make sure you have `cygwin-mount`, no space to post the link). That's if you want to do it by hand / not using Cygwin build.

Comment: For clarification, wvxvw's comment refers to integrating the native Windows build of Emacs (aka NTEmacs) with Cygwin, rather than installing Cygwin's Emacs package without using Cygwin's setup.exe package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Is it the case that you want to install the cygwin build of emacs, but don't want to use the Cygwin installer?  Or do you want to install the native emacs and access it from Cygwin?

While you *can* run the native emacs from Cygwin, I don't recommend it.  The unix style paths that Cygwin uses will not be recognized by the NT emacs.

If you want to use the Cygwin emacs, why do you not want to install it using the Cygwin installer?  This is by far the most convenient method.  However, you can install packages from the command line using setup.  See the last two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line).