# Where is the cygwin setup.exe binary when installed with the Chocolatey package manager?

Tags: windows, cygwin, chocolatey

I am working on a system automation process which will use Powershell to install Chocolatey to install Cygwin. I would subsequently like to install the prerequisites for apt-cyg, which will allow me to programatically install packages from cygwin. However, I do not know where the setup.exe binary for Cygwin is placed when installed with Chocolatey.

Comment: Are you using this exact package? https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the [cygwin](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin) package and inspected the `chocolateyInstall.ps1`. Looks like the package downloads the `exe` installer and passes the target folder.

```
$binRoot = Get-BinRoot
$cygRoot = join-path $binRoot "cygwin"
$cygPackages = join-path $cygRoot packages

# https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli
$silentArgs = "-q -R $cygRoot -l $cygPackages -s http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/"
$validExitCodes = @(0)

Install-ChocolateyPackage "$packageName" "$installerType" "$silentArgs" "$url" "$url64"  -validExitCodes $validExitCodes
```

The target folder is combined using the Chocolatey "binroot" folder. Here's where this gets messy... There are a bunch of legacy locations for this folder. The foolproof method is to import the Chocolatey helper module and execute `Get-BinRoot`. You need to find your Chocolatey install folder, too.

```
PS> Import-Module $ENV:CHOCOLATEYINSTALL\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1; Get-BinRoot
```

That will dump a folder name, on my system (and most systems with the latest Chocolatey and no manual changes to that path or any other Environment variables)

```
C:\tools
```

So, the cygwin binaries should be under some path like

```
C:\tools\cygwin
```

---

FYI, the cygwin package does recommend installing the cyg-get package for this kind of thing.

[image: cygwin and cyg-get]

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to where you can find the `setup.exe`, but you can actually use some *package manager* for Cygwin to manage packages. Some of them are standalone applications or scripts, some of them are just wrappers around Cygwin's `setup.exe`. Check my answer to [How do I install cygwin components from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line/23143997#23143997) for a list of some of them.

Also, there is the [`cyg-get` in the Chocolatey's repository](http://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get), which is, in fact, a wrapper around the `setup.exe` written in PowerShell.