# Can't instal some dependencies on windows 8

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm trying to install TURN server on windows 8, i'm following [THIS LINK](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html),
so he mentioned just Follow all steps from above section.
E.g.
Install all dependencies;
LibEvent and TURN modules. and I don't know how to make those commands work on windows 8
First Step: Download & Install Prerequisite for CentOS:

```
yum install -y make gcc cc gcc-c++ wget
yum install -y openssl-devel libevent libevent-devel mysql-devel mysql-server
```

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part of the instructions on that web page. You need to scroll down that page to the section marked "TURN installation on Windows". `yum` is a utility on CentOS (a Linux distribution) for installing applications.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear i guess you didn't read what i wrote .  i wrote that  ** he mentioned just to follow all steps from above section E.g. install all dependencies; LibEvent and TURN modules  ** and the command that he use is for CentOS so i want to know how to install thoes dependencies in windows

Comment: Perhaps [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line) will help you, then. Alternatively, when you install cygwin (which is quite involved) you may find the packages mentioned in the list of components to install.

Comment: [This page](https://www.fir3net.com/UNIX/Linux/cygwin-package-installation.html) may also help you.