# How can I install a C compiler on windows 8? I do not want to use an IDE

Tags: c, windows-8, cygwin

I have Cygwin, but can't figure out how to install GCC, Nano, Emacs or anything of the sort. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: lol, 'I do not want to use an IDE'.  inb4 SO questions with no debugging done because command-line gdb is too much work.

Comment: Mingw is very easy to install. Basically run an exe file and press "yes" a couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select the installation of gcc and g++ when installing cygwin.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Also a quick google search gave me [this](http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line) which may also answer your question about nano and emacs

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check this out.

Comment: No problem. If the problem is solved, remember to tick this as "answered"

Answer (score 0):

you can use [TDM](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) . A compiler suite for 32- and 64-bit Windows based on the GNU toolchain