# How to process json in bash script in windows environment

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, jq

I am writing bash script that is supposed to work both on linux and windows environment. To enable bash on windows we have installed cygwin. 
Seems jq lib can handle json but not sure will it work on windows environment too?
Same with sed not sure how to enable it in windows environment?
Some other libraries?

Comment: Have you tried running `sed` or `jq` inside cygwin ? Try copy/pasting your commands from one environment to the other and see if they work (Hint : they should)

Comment: no jq has not worked. I checked my cygwin64\bin folder and did not found any jq exe program. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/   downloaded and put in exe in bin folder. still jq is working from bash prompt

Comment: what happens when you type `jq --help` in cygwin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have jq installed on cygwin and it can handle json data in Windows.

You can install jq on Cygwin by two ways

1) Run this in cmd. setup-x86_64.exe is your cygwin installation binary

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P jq
```

2) Install apt-cyg(the package manager of cygwin similar to yum) and run on cygwin

```
apt-cyg install jq
```

NOTE: The details of installing packages on Cygwin is mentioned [How do I install cygwin components from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line)

Comment: #3 use setup in graphic mode https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: @matzeri, 1st point is already covering your 3rd point. It is actually invoking the installer in quiet mode