# Get Data JSON in Flask

Tags: python, json, curl, flask, cmd

Even following many example here & there, i can't get my API work in POST Method.
Here the code about it :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

@app.route('/api/v1/lists', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    print("p0")
    content = request.get_json()
    appname = content.get('title')
    print(content)
    print(appname)
```

When i query with curl (i'm running it on Windows):

curl.exe -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"titi"}' http://localhost:5000/api/v1/lists

curl.exe -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""title""":"""Read a book"""}" http://localhost:5000/api/v1/lists

I have always a 400 error in return:

HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.1 Python/3.6.0
Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 21:55:29 GMT

400 Bad Request
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I dont see where the error is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For others:  `POST`ing json via curl on Windows requires the quotes to be escaped differently, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498151/882436

Answer (score 7):

Even with the "working" code, in case of your if-block failure (when `value1` and `value2` is `None`) will cause the same error, since you are not handling the `else` part of the if-block. The corrected should be:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/list', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    print("p0")
    request_json     = request.get_json()
    value1           = request_json.get('First_Name')
    value2           = request_json.get('Last_Name')
    response_content = None

    if value1 is not None and value2 is not None:
        print("p3")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO person (first_name,last_name) VALUES (%s,%s)", (value1, value2))
        response_content = conn.commit()

    return jsonify(response_content)
```

Of course you may want something better than `None` as the response.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_entry` function isn't returning a response. You must return *something* even if it's just `return 'OK'`.

**EDIT:** You're still not returning anything. In `Flask` the Python `print` statement is not the equivalent of PHP's `echo`. All `print` does is print to the console. You still have to return a value. If what you need is to return `content` and `appname` JSON encoded, then add

`return json.loads({'contents': contents, 'appname': appname})`

to the end of your function.

And to be clear **in Flask views must return a value. That Python functions implicitly return None is inconsequential. The error that's occurring is that your function has no return statment.**

Comment: Flask doesn't like it.

Comment: i forget to add the print in the initial post.
but i still have the issue error 400 when i used the curl
And the print doesnt return anything in the console, only "p0" is print.

Answer (score 1):

Here a code working in my case :

```
@app.route('/api/v1/list', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    print("p0")
    request_json = request.get_json()
    value1 = request_json.get('First_Name')
    value2 = request_json.get('Last_Name')
    if value1 is not None and value2 is not None:
        print("p3")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO person (first_name,last_name) VALUES (%s,%s)", (value1, value2))
        data = conn.commit()
        return jsonify(data)
```