# Property of class cannot be null error when making curl POST request to REST api in Grails 4

Tags: rest, grails, grails-4, grails-rest-api

I created a new Grails 4.0.10 app using rest application profile.
I would like to check how the Resource annotation works. According to the docs, if I annotate Resource on domain then I don't need to write a controller.

The domain I have is:

```
package book
import grails.rest.Resource
@Resource(uri='/books', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Book {
    String title
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I run the app. When I run this `curl` command to create a book:

```
`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Along Came A Spider"}'` localhost:8080/books
```

I get the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange

but i tried in windows cmd prompt

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Along Came A Spider"}' localhost:8080/books
```

it thows error

but when i tried in Git Bash

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Along Came A Spider"}' localhost:8080/books
```

it succeeds

Comment: It seems as a problem with Windows terminal running curl query, not a Grails issue. Please check similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834238/curl-post-command-line-on-windows-restful-service