Can't Get cURL Windows Command Line to pass JSON to PHP and retrieve the variables in PHP, always null
I have tried examples from all over the globe and all have the same result.  I know it must be something simple that I am missing.  I am running in a Windows 11 cmd, no errors are returned and it does call the PHP script but can't get the JSON in the PHP script. I tried http and https as well.
cURL Version:
curl 8.4.0 (Windows) libcurl/8.4.0 Schannel WinIDN
Release-Date: 2023-10-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe Unicode UnixSockets

Here is the command:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"John Doe","age":30,"city":"New York"}' http://myserver/hello.php

Below is the PHP script, excuse the lines that are commented out for they reflect different things I have tried. Note I want to pass JSON not http://myserver/hello.php?name=John Doe&...
hello.php
<?php
  //header('content-type: application/json');
  //$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  //$data = var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
  //$data = var_dump(json_decode($_GET, true));
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    //$data = json_decode($_POST);
    //$data = $_POST;
  //$dump = print_r($data);
  //$dump = print_r($data);
    //$arrayJSON = json_decode($str_json);
    
  //$data = json_decode($_POST);
  

    file_put_contents('test.txt', $data['name']);
?>


So what does PHP think file_get_contents('php://input') contains (without running it through json_decode first)? Have you debugged it? What output do you get in the test.txt currently? "can't" isn't really a useful description of the problem...we need to know what does happen more than we need to know what doesn't happen, in order to make a diagnosis. Thanks.

It returns '{name:John Doe,age:30,city:New York}'

If it returns exactly what you've just showed me then that isn't valid JSON (the quote marks are missing round the property names and the values), so json_decode will fail. But that doesn't correlate with what you showed us that you sent in the curl command. So are you sure this is the result of the same command?

Maybe I need to escape the quotes in the curl?

This would suggest so, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834238/curl-post-command-line-on-windows-restful-service

Thanks I was stuck in an endless loop on this the answer is: -d "{""name"":""John Doe"",""age"":30,""city"":""New York""}"

If you have an answer please write it in the Answer box, not in the comments! Glad you fixed it

The problem in the original -d had to do with escaping quotes.  I will actually be using this in a Linux environment and I believe the original -d will work in Linux however I have not tested it yet.
Original -d
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"John Doe","age":30,"city":"New York"}' http://myserver/hello.php 

Fixed -d (at least for Windows)
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{""name"":""John Doe"",""age"":30,""city"":""New York""}" http://myserver/hello.php

