# Why does not working git clone in cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

I tried git clone for install googletest as below,
But the repository didn't copy to local

```
~/googletest$ git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
Cloning into 'googletest'...
~/googletest$
```

```
~/googletest$ strace --mask=sigp git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
--- Process 10372 created
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007ff990390000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007ff98f920000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007ff98db70000
--- Process 10372 loaded D:\@DevDocs\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll at 0000000180040000
--- Process 10372 loaded D:\@DevDocs\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll at 00000005461d0000
--- Process 10372 loaded D:\@DevDocs\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll at 00000005ee2d0000
--- Process 10372 loaded D:\@DevDocs\cygwin64\bin\cygpcre2-8-0.dll at 0000000453a70000
--- Process 10372 loaded D:\@DevDocs\cygwin64\bin\cygz.dll at 0000000597fd0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 00007ff98f870000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 00007ff98e3f0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 00007ff9902b0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 00007ff98ef90000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll at 00007ff98d480000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll at 00007ff98e030000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\wwglhk64.dll at 00007ff957860000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll at 00007ff98f0c0000
--- Process 10372 thread 24248 created
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\WwPsProtect64.dll at 00007ff9577d0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00007ff98e9b0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll at 00007ff98de40000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 00007ff98fdb0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll at 00007ff98de70000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll at 00007ff98e350000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ff98e250000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 00007ff98eb60000
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 00007ff9903f3416
--- Process 10372 thread 18112 created
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\PrintHK64.dll at 00007ff957500000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll at 00007ff98c710000
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018013ae2c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
--- Process 10372, exception c0000005 at 000000018006238c
```

I have re-installed the libcurl4 accordig to below answer,
[git/cygwin silent failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176526/git-cygwin-silent-failure)
But I could not solve this..

Comment: `c0000005` is an "access violation". This usually indicates *some* kind of installation trouble, but it's not necessarily that one particular library. The address `00007ff9903f3416` is a clue but what it means more precisely I can't tell you (I don't use Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Something (Antivirus ?) is injecting unexpected DLLS

```
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\wwglhk64.dll at 00007ff957860000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\WwPsProtect64.dll at 00007ff9577d0000
--- Process 10372 loaded C:\WWCNT\system\PrintHK64.dll at 00007ff957500000
```

so likely they are interfering with Cygwin processes blocking files in the wrong moment

https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda