# Installing RVM using Cygwin on windows - Curl throws status 23

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ssl

$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 861)

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '23'.

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/stable.tar.gz
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 15973)

Could not download 'https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '23'.

Been three days since I am struggling with this. Setup proxy, installed wget. I am trying to install RVM for windows 8.
For one of my projects I am not able to execute 'ruby pushGCM.rb'. It throws SSL Certificate error for which I need RVM desperately

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you tried pik? https://github.com/vertiginous/pik

Comment: yes I have but I need to run the command "rvm osx-ssl-certs update all" to get rid of the certificate issue. "pik osx-ssl-certs update all" doesnt recognise this command

Answer (score 2):

I've been fighting this issue for the past few days as well, and literally JUST figured it out for my issue.

Make sure you have CURL installed for cygwin, and that 'which curl' is pointing to that one.

I had Git Bash installed as well, and it was using the bundled curl that came with it - which apparently didn't play nicely with cygwin.

Also, in case you need any dependencies installed, I suggest putting the setup-x86.exe in your %CYGWIN_INSTALL_PATH%/bin/ so it will auto-install them adhoc.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I have installed curl and 'which curl' is pointing to this :

$ curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
$ which curl
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/curl

My Cygwin is in C:\cygwin64. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Following these instructions worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647569/how-do-i-install-curl-on-cygwin#answer-7559640