# Why is c curl + libcurl library refusing to link correctly under cygwin?

Tags: c, curl, cygwin, libcurl

I have been Googling for the past hour or two, and still no solution has surfaced. There are a lot of forum posts, stackoverflow posts, etc but most if not all are not linking the library (like at all).

I am compiling a sample script this one in particular: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html

**Background**

I have used the same method as this to install: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647569/how-do-i-install-curl-on-cygwin)

**First way**

Compiled using:

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall file_name -ofile_name.exe -lcurl
```

Results:

```
save.c:26:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
#include <curl/curl.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

*Note*

It seemed like curl was not getting unpacked or something.

**Second Way**

Downloading source and placing the curl dir with curl.h in user\include\curl.

I have been using variations of this to compile/build:

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall file_name -ofile_name.exe -lcurl
```

Curl library located here C:\cygwin64\usr\include\curl

Results:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Second Way**

Compiled using:

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall file_name -ofile_name.exe -Lcurl
```

Results:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0xe7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_global_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0xec): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_init'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x10d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x129): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x146): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x173): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_cleanup'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1aa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_cleanup'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1ce): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1eb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_setopt'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x1f7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curl_easy_perform'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/cygdrive/c/Users/user3624582/AppData/Local/Temp/ccHBcDdl.o:save.c:(.text+0x21b): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
```

**Things tried**

Use cygwin to download source (not just binary like before)

Use cygwin to reinstall curl / libcurl

use cygwin to uninstall and install curl / libcurl

I have then tried downloading it from here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html Towards the bottom of the page for cygwin64.

After a fresh bin download from cygwin: [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSyse.png)

**Things not yet tried**

Crying

Ripping hair out

Comment: You have to install packages `libcurl` and `libcurl-devel` via cygwin. You will have files `libcurl.a` and `libcurl.dll.a` under `/usr/lib`. Do not download anything from curl.haxx.se. Use `-lcurl`, not `-Lcurl`.

Comment: @n.m. That did the trick. Respond with an answer so I can mark as solved. Why not download anything from curl.haxx.see? I wonder why this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647569/how-do-i-install-curl-on-cygwin/7559640#7559640 didn't mention devel or anything else for that matter. Also somewhere I read devel as well as .a files are phased out for curl?

Comment: The linked question asks about the curl executable, not libraries to develop with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All paths below are cygwin paths, not Windows paths.

In the cygwin package manager (normally available as `/setup` from the shell) select `libcurl` and `libcurl-devel` packages. Do not download anything from `curl.haxx.se`. Cygwin has everything build just right for your environment, and its package manager takes care of dependencies for you.

Only if you for some reason need packages built by `curl.haxx.se` (e.g. you absolutely need the latest and greatest version not adopted by cygwin), download them from `curl.haxx.se`. Do **not** overwrite files installed by cygwin; instead, put libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, headers in `/usr/local/include`, and executables and DLLs in `/usr/local/bin`. Otherwise cygwin will happily thrash your files next time you update it. Add corresponding `-I` and `-L` flags to your compilation command. You are on your own with the DLL search path. You can add  `/usr/local/bin` to PATH, but then you are open to your own private version of DLL hell. You will also have to make sure you are downloading files for the right architecture, and track dependencies by hand. In short, don't do that unless you know exactly what you are doing and why you need it.

If you use the cygwin package manager, use just `-lcurl` linker flag. If you download files from `curl.haxx.se` (don't do that), use `-I/usr/local/include` for compilation and `-L /usr/local/lib` for linking, in addition to `-lcurl`. Note `-l` and `-L` are different flags.

Comment: Great write up! Very clear. Definitely took away a few things for next time.